# How do I use Bootstrap Lightbox with AngularJS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, lightbox

I have the following setup:

- Rails 4.0 running on Heroku
- jquery-rails and jquery-ui-rails gems
- ui-bootstrap-tpls.js from [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) (0.6)
- bootstrap-lightbox.js from [Bootstrap Lightbox](https://github.com/jbutz/bootstrap-lightbox)

Unfortatunatly when I load a page, even without an actual lightbox image on it, I get the following Javascript error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constructor' of undefined`

This happens here:

```
// We depend upon Twitter Bootstrap's Modal library to simplify things here
Lightbox.prototype = $.extend({},$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype);
```

Am I doing something wrong or should I not try to combine bootstrap-lightbox with Angular UI's Bootstrap? In the latter case, should I just try to reproduce the Lightbox functionality in Angular myself?

Comment: it looks like it might be a load order thing. Is Bootstrap loaded before this? `$.fn.modal` is loaded by bootstrap

Comment: @MatthewRudy yes Bootstrap is loaded first, but it's an Angular specific version of Bootstrap, so I suspect that it's not compatible.

Comment: Alternatively, you could opt for Twitter Bootstrap + [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/).